# Limit on pinned tiles in TFS Team Project Overview page

Tags: tfs

Is there a limit to how many pinned tiles or work item charts you can have on the Team Project Overview page in TFS 2013 Update 4? If so, what is that limit?

Comment: Have you run into any issues?

Comment: No, but I was asked the question and I didn't have a solid answer. My take is that there really isn't a limit and the screen will just scroll, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific restrictions of this in [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/report/widget-catalog). So, you may create it as many as you wish.

However, it's also unlikely to be infinity. It should meet some hardware bottlenecks of your local machine, such as there is no enough memory to load the TFS Team Project Overview page.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick; that makes sense and fits with my assumption that there really is no hard limit as long as there are resources to load up the page.